# Create a symbolic link in the Mac OS X Finder

Tags: macos, mac, finder, symbolic-link

Is there a way to get the same functionality as the unix command `ln -s` in the Mac OS X Finder (OS 10.5)?  I want to be able to create symbolic links while working in Finder windows without opening the Terminal.

Note that the `Make Alias` command in Finder is not what I want because those aliases cannot be navigated in the Terminal (but links created with `ln -s` can be navigated by both the Terminal and Finder).

Comment: macOS really ought to provide this as an opt-in feature for power users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about that
[creating symbolic links in the Finder via AppleScript](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20061201041424401)  ?

Here's the most relevant script in that link:

```
on run
    open {choose file with prompt "Choose a file to create a symbolic link:" without invisibles}
end run

on open the_files
    repeat with i from 1 to (count the_files)
        try
            set posix_path to POSIX path of (item i of the_files)
            if posix_path ends with "/" then set posix_path to text 1 thru -2 of posix_path
            do shell script "ln -s " & quoted form of posix_path & " " & quoted form of (posix_path & ".sym")
        end try
    end repeat
end open
```

Just paste it into **AppleScript Editor** and save it as an ***application***. Then you can drag it over your finder's **toolbar** or link it on the **dock**.

Comment: The 2nd comment at that link, left by jonn8n, gives exactly the functionality I was looking for.  Although, I'm a bit surprised this is not possible within Finder itself.

Comment: Your link is rotten

Answer (score 28):

[SymbolicLinker](https://github.com/nickzman/symboliclinker) will do exactly what you're looking for, and it's free.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, SymbolicLinker still works in Mavericks 10.9.3.

Comment: Your link is dead. Did you link to this? http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10433/symboliclinker

Comment: SymbolicLinker is dead, at least as of Mavericks.

Comment: Just a note to confirm that this still works on Mojave.  Also worth noting that the Releases tab on the linked Github site has a .dmg with the service and installation instructions to save building it yourself.

Comment: Still works on Big Sur. Also available with Homebrew, `brew install symboliclinker`.

Answer (score 2):

An applescript at the [link](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20061201041424401) provided by user [nuc](https://superuser.com/users/5624/nuc) answered my question.  Here is the applescript reproduced in case that link disappears.

I preferred the script given by the commenter jonn8n, which was also reproduced as [Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/58177/2007/06/symboliclinks.html).

```
on run
    open {choose file with prompt ¬
        "Choose a file to create a symbolic link:" without invisibles}
end run
on open the_files
    repeat with i from 1 to (count the_files)
        try
            set posix_path to POSIX path of (item i of the_files)
            if posix_path ends with "/" then set posix_path to ¬
                text 1 thru -2 of posix_path
            do shell script "ln -s " & quoted form of posix_path ¬
                & " " & quoted form of (posix_path & ".sym")
        end try
    end repeat
end open
```

I saved this as an application using Script Editor and dragged the application to the Finder sidebar so I can now create symbolic links by dragging files or folders onto the application icon.

Answer (score 1):

[Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) adds this to your Finder, and adds a lot more features.

Answer (score 1):

Use Automator.app to create a *Service* that executes a bash script. This is simpler than AppleScript and more reliable than installing third-party software.

```bsh
for f in "$@"
do
    ln -s "$f" "$f.symlink"
done
```

[image: Make Symbolic Link.workflow]

Then you can access the *Make Symbolic Link* command under the *Services* menu:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible improvement on this script would be changing the run handler to use the currently selected files from the Finder, as so:

```
on run
    tell application "Finder" to set sel to selection
    open sel
end run
on open the_files
    repeat with i from 1 to (count the_files)
        try
            set posix_path to POSIX path of (item i of the_files as alias)
            if posix_path ends with "/" then set posix_path to ¬
                text 1 thru -2 of posix_path
            try
                do shell script "ln -s " & quoted form of posix_path ¬
                    & " " & quoted form of (posix_path & ".sym")
            on error
                try
                    do shell script "ln -s " & quoted form of posix_path ¬
                        & " " & quoted form of (posix_path & ".sym") with administrator privileges

                end try
            end try
        end try
    end repeat
end open
```

You could also edit [application]/Contents/Info.plist to add

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Just before the last </dict>. This would mean the app would run in the background, and wouldn't come to the front when you clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in Snow Leopard where SymbolicLinker doesn't work, you can create a Service with Automator to do either the Terminal command or AppleScript to create a symbolic link.

Comment: Actually SymbolicLinker does work on Snow Leopard since, at least december 2009.

Answer (score 0):

One more AS:

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (get selection)
        set p to POSIX path of (f as text)
        set p2 to POSIX path of (desktop as text) & name of f
        do shell script "ln -s " & quoted form of p & " " & quoted form of p2
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score -2):

Try looking here : http://www.techiecorner.com/528/how-to-create-shortcut-in-mac-os-x/

This is built into OSX already if you press the control key when you click on something.

Comment: Only it's not a symbolic link that's created. You can `cd` into a symbolic link to a folder, but not into a Finder alias. Read the question, it already states this. (Moderators: We might want to leave this non-answer in, to prevent further answers along this line)

Comment: @daniel I doubt it will help much preventing, as answers in this line typically come from non-reading-people. :P