# Linked Files and Folders in OSX from Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, shortcuts, finder, symbolic-link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a symbolic link in the Mac OS X Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/24095/create-a-symbolic-link-in-the-mac-os-x-finder)

I use

```
ln -s original new
```

to make linked directories in OSX, but there must be a way using my mouse... no?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of 'Create a symbolic link in the Mac OS X Finder', http://superuser.com/questions/24095/create-a-symbolic-link-in-the-mac-os-x-finder?

Comment: @Jonik: Yes, methinks it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an alias with the Finder.  Ctrl-Click "Make Alias."  These aren't strictly unix symbolic links.

The Mac aliases will show as empty files in the terminal, pretty much unusable by Darwin.  They do what you expect in the GUI, though.

I don't think there is a way to do a Unix symbolic link with the finder.

Comment: So for maximum flexibility, using ln wouldn't be a bad idea... or is there a downside?

Comment: I guess the downside is that you have to use a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the folder you want to link, choose "Make Alias". (p.s not the same as a symbolic link, but works similar)