# Adding Folder to Finder Sidebar with Custom Name

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, finder

I'd like to add a a shortcut to Finder's Places Sidebar. The folder's name happens to be Applications, so I want to give it a different name since there's already the standard Applications folder there.

Renaming the folder on the sidebar renames the actual folder, which is undesirable because I think it might break the program which uses it.

I've tried making an alias, and then dragging the alias to the Sidebar, but the real name gets used.

Do you know how I can create this shortcut on the sidebar with a different name?

Comment: Just to save others the thirty seconds it takes to try: symlinks don't work either.

Comment: What about aliases?

Comment: When I put an alias in the Sidebar the real name of the folder is used, not the alias' name.

Comment: Looks like this has changed in latest macOS. I'm using Ventura, and when I make an alias of the folder with a custom name, and drag the alias to the sidebar, it retains the alias name. Although it has a file icon, when clicked, it takes me to the actual folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before anything, you should try renaming the folder. It will most likely not break your app because of how HFS works. But there are indeed some applications that might not link properly to files.

I could come up with 4 different solutions:

1. This may be the simplest: **do it the other way around**. Use whatever name you like on the folder and add an Alias to it. Grab the folder with the name you want and add it to the sidebar. The alias will not change. In your instance, you'd rename your `Applications` from within your "*username*" folder to something like `My Applications` and as we already know, that would be the enforced name on the sidebar. Then add an alias (or a [symlink](https://superuser.com/questions/24095/create-a-symbolic-link-in-the-mac-os-x-finder)) to it called `Applications`, which will probably work for your program.

   As Daniel said as a comment, you can aditionally hide the alias or the folder (but not the symlink) from finder by using: `chflags hidden folder/alias`. Use `chflags nohidden folder/alias` to show it again and with `ls -lO` (that's a capital <kbd>o</kbd>) you can see its flags on **Terminal**.
2. **Use a savedSearch**. You can name them whatever you want. Steps:

   1. go to that alternate `Applications` folder
   2. begin a search typing anything
   3. clear whatever you typed in
   4. select "*File Name*" (rather than "Contents") and *your folder* (rather than "This Mac")
   5. press the `+` sign
   6. press on `Kind` to add *Other*
   7. choose **File Visibility** and suit your taste
   8. press "*Save*", choose any name leaving the ".savedSearch" intact
   9. make sure "Add to Sidebar" is ticked.
3. If you prefer trying the **hack**, good luck with it. Basically you would edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` (use Property List Editor if you have XCode installed) and change the Name of your custom **useritems** and restart Finder. Supposedly <kbd>option</kbd>+*right click* on Finder and **Relaunch** would do this last trick. I couldn't myself reproduce this and make it work, but maybe it will if you reboot the machine. I doubt anyone would ever build any tweaker for such an overlooked feature.
4. [ForkLift](http://www.binarynights.com/) is a great **Finder alternative** that will accept aliases on the sidebar.

Comment: I tried 3) also and it didn't work. I'm afraid Finder ignores the name set in the `plist`. I like the symlink approach though. Additionally, while it somewhat duplicates the directory, `chflags hidden dirname` can hide one of them in Finder.

Comment: @Daniel yeah, maybe 3 isn't such a good idea after all... But I didn't bother trying it again. I'll wait to see if anyone else can confirm it before removing it. :P And good idea on the hiding, didn't know about it.

Comment: @Daniel I love when others edit my posts for positive contributions. This once this guy changed my whole post, and it looked so much more professional afterwards. I'm not that good of a writer after all, and he demonstrated himself an awesome one. If you can recall this, feel free to edit anything from me. If I don't like it, I can always revert or discuss or whatever (that also happened before).

Comment: @Daniel way more precisely said but still what I meant. And I can see the link plus I could find it from the prior link as well. So don't need to be *that* high rep. If you don't like edits for things like that, I can't see why. I had similar issues and I fought for them, and reverted. And learned a little bit in the run. Maybe your specific example has nothing to teach you so, if you got a lot of those I can see how it can stack up on your patience meter and why you don't like 'em. But there must be something that can be done if this is the hassle. The edit feature is very good otherwise.

Comment: I've been using #2. Thanks for your help. I didn't mark it as a solution though, because I wasn't sure if the other options were better. Being new to OS X I didn't want to try something I didn't understand, or understand how to undo.

I'll try the other suggestions when my project is complete, and can afford to troubleshoot any unforeseen downtime.

Comment: @Louis that's just fine dude. You know you can "accept" (not same as marking as solution, but quite alike) any answer at any time, and simply change the accepted answer later at your will, as many times as you want. I still highly recommend option #1, that's why I've added as first :P - and it's easy to undo as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use an application instead.

Open `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor` and enter the following:

```
tell application "Finder" to set target of first window whose index is 1 to (POSIX file "/Users/danielbeck/Applications")
```

Save as application anywhere you like (see below for hint on this) and drag it from there to the Finder sidebar. Clicking This will navigate the frontmost Finder window to the specified folder.

To give it a "real" *Applications* Finder sidebar icon, navigate to `/System/Library/CoreServices`, right-click and *Show Package Contents* on `CoreTypes.bundle`. Then open `Contents/Resources` and open `ToolbarAppsFolderIcon.icns` in preview. Select the smallest version from the sidebar and press `Cmd-C`, then *Get Info* on your AppleScript application, select the icon and press `Cmd-V` to paste the *Applications* icon onto your application.

[image]

Drawbacks:

- No "selected" state in the sidebar when in the Applications folder
- Annoying (and ugly, since the selected icon is so tiny) animation whenever starting the application to navigate to the folder
- Doesn't *really* work with file dialogs (e.g. *Open…* and *Save as…*). Selecting it then will open the folder where you stored the application (so store it in the folder you want to link it to!)
- Cannot `Command-Click` to open in a new window (might be possible through advanced AppleScript-fu).

Comment: That's just fugly. Also, if you use `set target` in column view, it shows all the columns starting from the volume, not starting from the last location kept in the sidebar.

Comment: @Lri Provide a better solution then. Localization doesn't work without renaming the folder to `Name.localized`, so I tried this, and it somewhat works. I wouldn't use it, but someone might think it's useful. See that section *drawbacks*? Even I recognize it's not that good.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me. I create an alias, renamed to something like -> Application and then put it in the Favorites section of the sidebar. That way it won't actually rename the folder. If I tried to put it in the iCloud section it reverted back to the folder name.

Comment: "Putting an alias" in the Favourites just puts the Original in there instead

Comment: @Hicsy it works now. Tested in Ventura.

Answer (score 1):

You could rename the folder, while putting a symlink called "Applications" pointing to it inside its parent directory. Then all paths going through foo/Applications would continue to work.