# Modifying Finder sidebar "Places" links

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I'm using Mac 10.6, Snow Leopard.

I've dragged a link to my sidebar for the folder, /Library/WebServer/Documents. How do I change the icon displayed in the sidebar, and also rename the link, without renaming the target folder?

Comment: Good question! (I tried the obvious way of making an alias, and that doesn't work.)

Comment: You can't. This question was posted a while ago with no good solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Folder to Finder Sidebar with Custom Name](http://superuser.com/questions/258684/adding-folder-to-finder-sidebar-with-custom-name)