# Permission Denied when try calling "sh -c SOMEALIAS" on mac terminal

Tags: bash, mac, terminal, permissions

On mac I made an alias to mitmdump and then I tried through terminal

```
sh -c fullpathto/mitmdump # works
sh -c fullpathto/mitmdump_alias # Permission Denied error
```

while double click of mitmdump_alias also works too.

So how can I correctly make alias called through sh?

I don't think this problem specified to mitmproxy but in case you can get

```
brew install mitmproxy
```

and it locates in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mitmproxy/4.0.4/libexec/bin/mitmdump
```

Comment: By "alias" do you mean a symbolic link?

Comment: I just right click the original mitmdump in mac finder and "Make Alias". I don't quite know about symbolic link.

Comment: Going by https://superuser.com/questions/24095/create-a-symbolic-link-in-the-mac-os-x-finder/, command line tools don't support those aliases well. You should make a symbolic link instead.

Comment: Oh perfect. This is totally what I want. Thanks!